# Switching branches while running python unit tests

Tags: python, git, unit-testing

This is more of a general question about safety in testing than a specific code problem.  Lets say I have feature branch for my `git` repository, I always run a suite of unit tests before I merge back into develop or master.  But these unit tests often take a while (on the order of an hour).  So I generally kick off the test and then change branches in my repository so I can work on coding other things...I'm assuming this is safe because the .pyc files are already created?

Comment: Does your library defer any import statements?  Also, why do you have unit-tests that take an hour to run -- That seems a bit excessive... :-)

Comment: I concur - if your unit tests take more than several seconds (maaaybe a couple of minutes) you might want to reconsider what you're testing! Or break your insanely massive totally huge project into a few smaller more cohesive ones.

Comment: To clarify, most of my unit tests are quite small (a few minutes tops).  However I have quite a few of them (so total test time is about an hour).  There are a few test cases that take a while because they are stress testing model training and I need to pull together a large standard set to train on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you offload test execution to a proper continuous-integration system such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/). Switching out the entire source tree in the middle of a test run is bound to cause weird problems.

Also consider that your test suite likely contains both unit tests and *integration* tests. Unit tests should be fast! A runtime of 0.1 seconds is a slow unit test. Tests that touch the filesystem, communicate with a database, send packets over the network, and so on are integration tests. You might scale those back to running once or twice a day. See *Working Effectively With Legacy Code* by Michael Feathers.

Comment: I've used Jenkins before, never used Travis...do you have any quick pointers on the difference between the two?

Comment: @sedavidw Travis is hosted, and really only Linux based at the moment.  See https://travis-ci.com/ for more information.  They have similar capabilities, but how you drive them is completely different.  Personally, I'd recommend [QuickBuild](http://www.pmease.com/)--it's much better than Jenkins, IMHO, and there is a free version of QuickBuild.

Answer (score 1):

If proper CI is not a preferred option for whatever reason and you are OK with some scripting, then you could do a script that would copy a git revision (git export or [git new workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) + checkout there ) and execute tests in that location while you keep going further with changes. Worked fine for me with a large java project.